# why does [XMLHttpReequest] Message come?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am calling below javascript/ajax page method from code behind, then
why does [XMLHttpReequest] Message come?

```
var options = {
  type: "POST",
  url: "Test.aspx/SendMessage",
  data: "{'toMailAddress':'" + val + "','rno':'" + rno+ "', 'nonrno':'" + nonrno+ "'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
    var val1 = response.d;
    alert(val1);
    if (val1 == "1") {
      // Below code is used to close the window, if message has been sent to the user sucessfully.
      var windowObj = window.self;
      windowObj.opener = window.self;
      windowObj.close();
    }
  },
  error: function (result) {
    alert("Error in " + result);
  }
};
$.ajax(options);
```

Comment: You have an error in your script, in the last line it should be `$.ajax(options);`, assuming that is you are trying to call jQuery's ajax method ?

Comment: Do you mean an alert window is displayed with the text `[XMLHttpRequest]` in it ?

Comment: No, My page method return a string, i am trying to show return message, every thing going fine. but at the end i mean after showing the return message as well as closing window message, it show         object XMLHttpRequest message, why does object [XMLHttpRequest] message come?

Comment: You `options` object was also missing the closing brace, I've edited the question to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the message you are in fact seeing is "Error in XMLHttpRequest". This is what you would see if an error occurred during the call, because you have the wrong arguments for the error call back.

The method signature for the jQuery ajax error callback is:

```
error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

So your error alert is being passed the `XMLHttpRequest` object, which is probably not what you meant to do. The code implicitly calls the `toString()` method on the `XMLHttpRequest` which will return `"[object XMLHttpRequest]"`.

If that message isn't coming from the error callback, then there must be another bit of code somewhere passing the `XMLHttpRequest` object to `alert()`. I suggest you set a break point after your own `alert()` and single step through to see where the other `alert()` is.

Comment: i have changed my error code as u suggest, but still [Object XMLHttpRequest] message come. i told u every thing is going fine but why does [Object XMLHttpRequest] message come?                                                               Code u suggest                                                                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error in " + result);
  }

Comment: There is an error in that bit of code, there is no `result` variable.